# TFS hook with Service Management application

Tags: tfs

We use a Service Management software called ITSM. We want to know if it's possible to hook this software with TFS, so when a bug is raised, a new workitem is created in TFS? It doesn't have to be ITSM, we just want to know how can this be done and then may be we can customise it for ITSM or any Service Management software we procure in the future?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. TFS 2015 supports a new feature called Service Hooks that can be used to integrate two systems. Any two systems.

If you are using an older version of TFS you will need to use the client API to create that sort of integration. I built integration between ITSM and TFS when I worked at Merrill Lynch back in the day. Worked ok and allowed a bug to be raised in tfs from ITSM and kept limited sync.

You may want to look to Task Top for commercial integration between ITSM and TFS.

Comment: we are currently using TFS 2013. I have asked TaskTop for a quote but do you know if there are any open source libraries available? while upgrading to tfs 2013 update 5, i saw microsoft installed a component called Service Hooks is available. does that mean it's available in update 5 for tfs 2013?